# Schedule task in Windows Task Scheduler C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

My application requires a re-start at midnight time daily. For this job, according to me, the task scheduler would be the ideal thing to use but I haven't been able to find how to use the Task Scheduler APIs in C# (no external libraries to be used)

Once starting the application from Task Scheduler is done, I also wanted suggestions how to shutdown the application automatically at a certain time (even if the app at that particular time might be unresponsive, displaying some error message box or not working due to some problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I suppose you don't know about the `schtasks` command.
You could simply open a command prompt and type `schtasks /?` to see the options available.
The one needed here is `/create`. Of course this option requires a series of parameter to configure your scheduled task. But at the end you could resolve all calling:

```
Process.Start("schtasks", commandParams);
```

For the close process part, I use a little utility called `pskill` found in the [Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/sysinternals/bb896649) from Microsoft's Mark Russinovich. Also this could be called inside a batch file set as scheduled task.

EDIT: Changed from psshutdown to pskill (You need to close only your app right?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to set this task manually through command line first, and after running the `cmd` as administrator, I was able to create this task `schtasks /create /tn "MyApp" /tr c:\app.exe /sc on start` with the message `Successfully created the task`. Apparently, my app requires admin privileges to run and when I restarted the computer, the app didn't run. I checked in schticks /query and the MyApp status was shown as 'Could not start'. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I don't think it's because of this admin privileges. I tried another simple app which doesn't require admin previliges, but it gave 'Could not start' status when I checked in schtasks /query after restart.

Comment: I changed the task to logon and it runs fine now. :-)

Comment: @Steve Why not just use `Process.Kill`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you write a service to handle this. Also, why does it *require a restart*?

If however *you must* use task scheduler, try it like this:

```
schtasks /create /SC DAILY /TN AppName /TR AppExecutablePath /ST 0
0:00 /ET TIMEFORENDTASK
```

You can simply type this in a batch script and run the batch script when the user is installing the app, then put this in the uninstall batch script:

```
schtasks /delete /TN AppName
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to set this task manually through command line first using schtasks` command, and after running the cmd as administrator, I was able to create this task schtasks /create /tn "MyApp" /tr c:\app.exe /sc on start with the message Successfully created the task. Apparently, my app requires admin privileges to run and when I restarted the computer, the app didn't run. I checked in schticks /query and the MyApp status was shown as 'Could not start'. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Probably you need to pass user name and password of the administrator. See the flags /U /P and also /RU

Comment: I don't think it's because of this admin privileges. I tried another simple app which doesn't require admin previliges, but it gave 'Could not start' status when I checked in schtasks /query after restart.

Comment: @user1240679: It's `ONSTART` not `ON START`... Since this is on your PC, I suggest you use the GUI, that way you can avoid spelling mistakes or otherwise. Simply type `start taskschd.msc` in command prompt and use the *Create Task Wizard.*