# WPF show a pop message like a reminder every hour

Tags: wpf, task, scheduler

I am Creating a Reminder wpf application where user can select time, repeat type and seta reminder on his machine.
Based on his inputs I would like to add scheduled task. I need some help how to accomplish this using taskscheduler.(Nudget package) or if any other alternative.
I want to pop up a reminder window which I would create in my wpf application.
The Execute method of TaskScheduler allows triggering exe files. 
But how to open my reminder window as a trigger action? 
Please help...!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Schedule task in Windows Task Scheduler C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052638/schedule-task-in-windows-task-scheduler-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I did this long time ago, but I guess to setup the task we had one project and to show message we had another one.

[Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks) to see how to create a task, and in ExecAction provide path to your other application(pop up one)